# Combine multy arrays side by side google script

Tags: arrays, regex, google-apps-script, wildcard

I have this code on Google script for get arrays from Sheet1 by criteria in Sheet2 at Sheet3. But now arrays placed only one under the other. What I need is place every new array from 'v' in next 5 columns like in example on my spreadsheet.

Secondly - before this, I used filter with search formula, that allow me use wildcards like * or ?. How I can use wildcards or regexp in my new function?

I would be grateful for any help.

```
    function getval(){

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      var sspodbor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");

      var range = ss.getRange("A2:A29");
      var values = range.getValues();

      var rangez = sheet.getRange("A1:A14");
      var valuesz = rangez.getValues();

      var z = []
      for (var x = 0; x<valuesz.length; x++){
        z.push(valuesz[x])
      }

      var v = [];
      for (var q = 0; q < valuesz.length; q++){
        for (var s = 0; s < values.length; s++){
          if(values[s][5] ==  z[q]){
            v.push([values[s][0],values[s][1],values[s][2],values[s][3],values[s][4]]);
          }
//I am guessing that here must be a separating function       
        }
      }
      var range = sspodbor.getRange(4, 1, v.length,v[0].length);
      range.setValues(v);
    }
```

My spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o7ErbeFHA7yyxMC0HMn3Uj5ZBRcy2uAwa1UpolVpBFI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: A couple of small things: First var range = ss.getRange("A2:A29"); probably should be var range = ss.getRange("A2:F29"); and secondly var z = [] should be var z = []; But the big question for me is how are you grouping them.  Sheet2 only has 14 values. So only 14 values of q and yet you show 16 columns in your example.  So how are you grouping them,

Comment: Hello again, @Cooper ! Like you see, I learned something about arrays from you previous answer! I grouped them by very simple way: in loop with q var, I take one cell from rangez, and next in loop with s var I check if some value from values range equal to it, I push it to v array. And when I take next q var, I need again to push equal values from 0-4 to next columns

Comment: I ended up including the q value here: if(values1[s][5] ==  z[q]){       v.push([values1[s][0],values1[s][1],values1[s][2],values1[s][3],values1[s][4],q]);} along with your output data because it seemed to be common to each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Spreading the Groups out Horizontally

It's not the prettiest solution you'll ever see and hopefully others will look it over and make improvements but here it is.

```
function getval()
{
  var Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var output = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("output");
  var knew = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('knew');
  var knewrange = knew.getRange(1,1,10,100);
  var pipe = '';

  var range1 = Sheet1.getRange("A2:F29");
  var values1 = range1.getValues();

  var range2 = Sheet2.getRange("A1:A14");
  var values2 = range2.getValues();

  var z = [];  
  for (var x = 0; x<values2.length; x++)
  {
    z.push(values2[x])
  }
  var v = [];
  for (var q = 0; q < values2.length; q++)
  {
    for (var s = 0; s < values1.length; s++)
    {
      if(values1[s][5] ==  z[q])
      {
        v.push([values1[s][0],values1[s][1],values1[s][2],values1[s][3],values1[s][4],q]);
      }
    }
  }
  var vlength=v.length;  
  var range3 = output.getRange(1, 1, v.length,6);
  range3.setValues(v);

  var w = [];
  var voff = 0;
  var hoff = 0;
  for(var m=0;m<10;m++)
  {
    w[m]=[];
    for(var n=0;n<100;n++)
    {
      w[m][n]='' ;
    }
  }
  var color = ['yellow','orange'];
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<5;j++)
    {

      if(i-voff==0){knew.getRange((i-voff + 1),(j + hoff + 1),4,5).setBackground(color[v[i][5] % 2])};
      if((i-voff)==0 || v[i][5] == v[i-1][5])
      {
        w[i - voff][j + hoff]=v[i][j];
      }  
      else
      {
        voff = i;
        hoff += 5;
        w[i - voff][j + hoff]=v[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  knewrange.setValues(w);
}
```

I copied the data from your spreadsheet and the the original getval function.  I ended up changing some  of the names so I could figure out where to find the data easier. It was a difficult problem for me and one that i enjoyed. 
 Thanks

Comment: Hey, @Cooper ! Check out your answer - it work good, and it has a lot of functions and operators new to me that I must understand. When looking at your answer, I realized that it is sufficient to move SetValue in "q" loop, add another array to it, and set columt number 1 instead of (q+1)*5. Its so simple, thank you!

Comment: Yes adding q to the data set made it possible to have access to in the looping so that when q[i] !==q[i=1] then thats a group transistion I chose to create the w array and initialize to dimensions greater than I need so I would avoid getting dimension errors all of the time.  However, you need to be careful because updating a big array inside of a loop expends a lot of resources although refreshing the screen like that really helps to figure out what's going on.  You can probably make the size of w 5 * the number of groups by the max group size.